# iOS update tableheader height after image is downloaded (constraint is not updated)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an image in Tableheader like this.

[image]

After image is downloaded, I need to update height of that image and also update height for tableheader.

```
[self.ivMain setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.naturefineartphotos.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/utah_aspenfamilyportrait_1001.jpg"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGFloat height = (image.size.height/ image.size.width) * CGRectGetWidth(self.frame);
        [self.constraintIVMainHeight setConstant:height];

        [self.delegate setTableHeader];
    });

} usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

But tableheader height is not changed. I guess tableview restrict and I try to update my layout outside like this.

```
- (void)setTableHeader {
        [self.vwEventDetail removeFromSuperview];
        [self.tblDetail setTableHeaderView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]];
        [self.vwEventDetail layoutSubviews];
        [self.vwEventDetail setNeedsLayout];
        [self.tblDetail setTableHeaderView:self.vwEventDetail];
}
```

It is also not okay. How shall I do? If I use auto-resizing, it is easy. Why using constraint is difficult? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fact: Constraints doesn't apply to the tableheader view. It always needs to set its frame to resize.

**Problems:**

**(1)** you are layouting a view that does not have a superview. That doesn't work.

```
[self.vwEventDetail removeFromSuperview];
```

**(2)** when you set the tableview header the view you used became the header view. and header view doesn't work with height constraint. it will just ignore it. even if you layout it after you set it.

### Proposed solution:

1. Define a global int variable that holds the tableview all the time. init it with zero.
2. When download complete set the new height to that var.
3. update the height constraint on you image or its superview.
4. then, layout the controller view. (self.view).
5. in layout `viewDidLayoutSubviews` set the table header frame by using the height var.

> note: keep your views on the header view all the time. add them in
>   storyboard and don't remove it in runtime.

**Snapshot:**
[image]

**Code Sample (Swift):**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func donwloadFinished() {
        imageHeightConstraint.constant 
                  = (image.size.height/ image.size.width) * CGRectGetWidth(self.frame);
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.layoutSubviews()
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        headerView.frame = containerView.frame
    }
}
```

[Public github project](https://github.com/hasanalbukhari/dynamicheaderview)

Comment: It looks great. Thanks for detail explanation. I will only know image view height and won't know total table header frame height. How can I update table header height?

If possible, could you please explain with code for 3- 5? It will be a lot useful for me.

Comment: include a container view in the tableview header on storyboard. that container include all the views and the image. then when you know the height update the height contranit. and then layout the self.view and in viewDidLayoutSubviews set the header height. you need to do both the height contraint on the container view and the header frame height.

Comment: Can I see how you add subview headerView to  containerView? Do I need to set up constraint for those 2 view ?

Comment: Amm you are doing it from storyboard. I am setting 2 view programmatically.

Comment: on storyboard drag a view to the tableview as a placeholder(tableview). connect that with an outlet. add your views to it. set height constraint. then layout. I am creating a github project sample so you can check the constraints that you should add.

Comment: the idea is that the headerview itself. weather added by code or on storyboard shouldnt have a bottom constraint to its subviews.

Comment: I added the github url in the answer and edited some code. let me now when you manage to solve it.

Comment: wow. Thanks a lot. It solve my issue. I got two lessons from u. Your point 1 and about using viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: I have set my two view (header and container) programmatically based on your project.